# Why isn't a game purchased through Steam mobile showing in my PC library?

Tags: steam, steam-mobile

I have some problem after I purchased a game on Steam mobile, I can't find it on my game library on Steam PC. I am sure that I have logged in my account on both my mobile and PC, I can see that the game that I have purchased is there on the game library on Steam mobile.

How do I connect my Steam mobile game library to my Steam PC library ?

Comment: Are you *sure* that they're on the same account? You're supposed to use same account on both.

Comment: yes, I am sure I'm on the same account @Avery

Comment: Check your Steam email for the purchase receipt. Also, try restarting Steam on your PC?

Comment: doh lol I think I was mistakenly insert my second account, thanks @Robotnik

Comment: @aswinawien23 - Glad we sorted the issue out for you :-). I have added an answer to that effect as well as listing the option of obtaining a refund so you can purchase on the correct account. I have also removed the '[solved]' from the title as that's not how we do things, if you wish you can mark an answer as 'accepted' by clicking the checkmark under the answer's vote count.

Answer (score 5):

When you purchase a game on Steam you will receive a purchase receipt in your Steam account's email Inbox. It looks similar to this:

[image: Steam Purchase receipt]

If you do not have a receipt for your recent purchase in that Inbox, then you did not purchase the game with that account. Check your other Steam account's email addresses (if any) for the purchase receipt there.

If you did accidentally purchase the game with the wrong account and you haven't installed/played it yet, You should be able to request a refund from Steam then purchase it using the correct account. As per the image above, links to refund purchases are sent as part of the receipt.