# Steam wanting me to buy a game I already bought?

Tags: steam

So, someone else came over, signed into their account. I try to open GMod, and it asks me if I want to buy or ask permission, but I've already bought it. I've signed out the other person and it still asks the question.
Any suggestions?

Comment: From your game library or the store page for the game?

Comment: if you brought it then why are you accessing someone else's account? wouldn't it be in your account?

Comment: You say that you signed out of the other person's account, can we safely assume you also signed back in to *your* account?  I only ask to be sure, since you didn't actually say you did that part.

Comment: Yes I did sign back in. The problem is that it's still accessing it even though it shouldn't be.

Comment: [Find your purchase receipt](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/315324/28182), and ensure the game is purchased for the account that's currently logged in. If so, and it's still not showing up, contact Steam Support.

Answer (score 1):

You could use family share, by going to your username up at the top right, clicking it and going to Account Details.

[image: username>AccountDetails]

From here you can click Family Share, and manage all the people who can use your account.

OR

You can ask from permission from your friend and they will have to go through some short steps to allow you to play their games on your computer.

Just because a game is installed on your computer doesn't mean that it is in your Steam Library, ready to play. So you should use family share to do this.

*HINT* If you use family share, you two can't play the game at the same time.